# The Use of "evenings are usually clear"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-choice

We work during the week，but weekends and evenings are usually ________．

- A．vacant
- B．casual
- C．empty
- D．clear

This exam question, with D as the correct answer, puzzles me. Could someone show me more examples including the structure "sometime + be + clear"?

I was using the definitions of clear [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/clear).

Comment: Not enough context to give an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This definition is from the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/clear):

> **clear: NOT BLOCKED**
>   not busy or filled by any planned activity:
>   *The only time I have clear next week is Tuesday afternoon.*

I'm not sure, but I think that the free dictionary is *scraped* by 
robots that search other dictionaries online. The individual definitions may be correct, but they lack the context of the original dictionary, and are far from complete.

Better to get the information *from the horse's mouth* by looking at one of the
dictionaries written by humans, for example Oxford Dictionary, Cambridge Dictionary and Merriam-Webster.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard "clear" used this way, but sometimes we use [*free*](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=free):

> 6c. Not taken up by scheduled activities: free time between classes.

So it would be:

> We work during the week，but weekends and evenings are usually **free**．

though it might not apply if you were doing something other than your occupation (work around the house, fix the car, etc.), though the timing of these activities generally can be juggled.